# How to add JCheckBox in JTable?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jframe

First of all i apologize for my english neglect that i will explain all my problem.

First i want JCheckBox in the JTable i have.

I am retrieving student id and student name from database in column index 0 and 1. I want third column should be Absent/Present which will initially take whether student is present or absent by JCheckbox Value.

Here my code for JTable values :

**Attendance.java**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package shreesai;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class Attendance{

    Connection con = Connectdatabase.ConnecrDb();
    public Vector getEmployee()throws Exception
    {

        Vector<Vector<String>> employeeVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

        PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement("select studentid,name from student");
        ResultSet rs = pre.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {

            Vector<String> employee = new Vector<String>();
            employee.add(rs.getString(1)); //Empid
            employee.add(rs.getString(2));//name
            employeeVector.add(employee);

        }        
        if(con!=null)
        con.close();
        rs.close();
        pre.close();

        return employeeVector;
    }
}
```

**THIS CODE FOR TAKING VALUES FROM DATABASE SAVING IT INTO VECTOR**

**AttendanceGUI.java**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package shreesai;

import static java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class AttendanceGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form AttendanceGUI
     */
    private Vector<Vector<String>> data;
    private Vector<String> header;
    public AttendanceGUI() throws Exception {

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        Attendance att = new Attendance();
        data = att.getEmployee();

        header = new Vector<String>();
        header.add("Student ID");
        header.add("Student Name");
        header.add("Absent/Present");
        initComponents();
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        AttendanceT = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        AttendanceT.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            data,header
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(AttendanceT);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(397, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(89, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AttendanceGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AttendanceGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AttendanceGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AttendanceGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    new AttendanceGUI().setVisible(true);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTable AttendanceT;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

My problemis that I can't add a `JCheckBox` in front of every student I have seen `JTabel` model, renderer and all but I don't get anything. I want something like this...

[image]

I've search for this stuff for a couple of weeks but did bot get anything suitable for this

Comment: Where i am shouting ? I am explaining my problem.

Comment: +1 for code and screenshot.

Comment: @JavaTweaker writing in ALL CAPS is considered shouting.

Comment: sorry dahaka i will keep in mind from next time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start with [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Your table model needs several things.

1. It needs to return `Boolean.class` from the `getColumnClass` method for the appropriate column.  You will need to override this method.
2. The method `isCellEditable` will need to return `true` for the table column you want to make editable (so the user can change the value of the column)
3. You're table model will need to be capable of holding the value for the column
4. Make sure you pass a valid value for the `boolean` column for the row, otherwise it will be `null`

**Updated with simple example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TableTest();
  }

  public TableTest() {
    startUI();
  }

  public void startUI() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{0, "Brian", false});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{1, "Ned", false});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{2, "John", false});
        model.addRow(new Object[]{3, "Drogo", false});
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    public MyTableModel() {
      super(new String[]{"ID", "Name", "Present"}, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
      Class clazz = String.class;
      switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
          clazz = Integer.class;
          break;
        case 2:
          clazz = Boolean.class;
          break;
      }
      return clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
      return column == 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
      if (aValue instanceof Boolean && column == 2) {
        System.out.println(aValue);
        Vector rowData = (Vector)getDataVector().get(row);
        rowData.set(2, (boolean)aValue);
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Ps- I would HIGHLY recommend you avoid form editors until you have a better understanding of how Swing works - IMHO

Comment: @mKorbel I really, really don't like `DefaultTableModel`

Comment: can it be possible without making Any abstract Model??

Comment: Not really, the table requires the class type for the column to be Boolean in order for it to work

Comment: okey i got it and if i add this then i am not able to Resize column individual i tried this jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setWidth(50); but not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "resize column individual"? Do you mean by the UI or via the code? The TableModel has nothing to do with column sizes

Comment: means via code and ya i did it with jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100); and ya i have one more question. if i put auto resize off then only i am able to resize column width?

Comment: No you should be able to use a mixture of preferred/min/max width with auto resizing modes

Comment: i am not able to resize it with out auto resize off.

Comment: I have used setpreffered with. and with auto resizing off then it worked. but with out that is not working its giving auto with.

Comment: Consider producing a runnable example and posting a new question

Comment: @MadProgremmer i am blocked so i cant :( perhaps i can give mail :)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you add `Boolean` value as data into the table model, `DefaultCellRendered` will render it as checbox by itself, so where is the problem?

Comment: Not really.  Unless the `TableModel#getColumnClass` returns `Boolean.class`, the table will use the values `toString` as the value to be renderered....