# Adding JCheckBox into JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have a program to display database into a dynamic `JTable`. Its working fine. Now I want to add 1 more column into the table with CheckBox in each field. What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
public static DefaultTableModel myTableModel(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    ResultSetMetaData metadata = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
    int columnsCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < columnsCount; i++) {
        columnNames.add(metadata.getColumnName(i));
    }
    Vector<Object> data = new Vector<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> eachLine = new Vector<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < columnsCount; i++) {
            eachLine.add(rs.getObject(i));
        }
        data.add(eachLine);
    }
    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
}
```

Comment: I don't think showing us that piece of code will be much help. I do think you would find it more clear if you wrote your own `TableModel` though. You should create your own [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html).

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513)?

Comment: okay.how i can add 1 more column ?.

Comment: You should read on JTables, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html, you'll find a section on Using Custom Renderers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> okay.how i can add 1 more column ?.

You need to add a column for the name and for each row you add to the model. To add the columns at the beginning of the table you could do:

```
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
columnNames.add("Boolean");
...
Vector<Object> data = new Vector<>();
data.add(new Boolean(false));
```

There is no need to create a custom renderer, but as others have mentioned you need to override the getColumnClass() method to return Boolean.class for that column so the table can use the appropriate renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Boolean` field if you want checkbox in `JTable`.
False will be deselect and true value will represent selected checkbox.
You can find `Boolean` column type while adding a `JTable` if you are a NetBeans user.

For more check this SO que.

[How to add JCheckBox in JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099717/how-to-add-jcheckbox-in-jtable)

Comment: Note that should be Boolean, not boolean, since the model holds reference types, and the `getColumnClass(int columnIndex)` method override should return Boolean.class for that column.