# how can be Boolean value retrieve from database table into JCheckbox in JTable

Tags: java, swing

need a column in JTable which contain JCheckBox which is retrieve from Boolean datatype from database table.if Boolean value is true then JcheckBox should have tick or vice versa
kindly suggest a code

Comment: @bradimus i had tried to get all columns from database and yes it works properly but don't know how to process further. please suggest a code

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099717/how-to-add-jcheckbox-in-jtable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822376/display-jcheckbox-in-jtable

Comment: This links are useful but facing problem to retrieve Boolean value into Jcheckbox inJTable (using JDBC)and also if Boolean value is true then checkbox should be check or if false then checkbox should not have been check

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your implementation of `getColumnClass()`.

Comment: please provide a code for retrieving column from database which is of Boolean datatype and display it into JCheckbox in JTable